# Creating a macro: FancyVerb Error

Tags: macros

I wanted to create a consistent setting for `Verbatim` so I decided to create a macro out of this:

```
\newcommand*{\VerbatimCustom}{
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]
}
```

And use it like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\VerbatimCustom
module GRAMMAR[] begin
  phylum Grammar;

  phylum Item;
  phylum Items := SEQUENCE[Item];

  phylum Production;
  phylum Productions := SEQUENCE[Production];

  constructor terminal(s: Symbol) : Item;
  constructor nonterminal(s: Symbol) : Item;
  constructor prod(nt: Symbol; children: Items) : Production;
  constructor grammar(prods: Productions) : Grammar;

  pragma root_phylum(type Grammar);
end;    
\end{Verbatim}
    \caption{Structure of a context-free grammar in APS}
    \label{fig:cfg-structure}
\end{figure}
```

Error:

> Extraneous input ` ' between \begin{Verbatim}[<key=value>] and line
> end . \FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error: \space \space #1 }
> l.38 \VerbatimCustom
> This input will be discarded. Hit  to continue.

I appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: as @Ulrich shows, you can make this work but I'd strongly advise that you don't do that, the result is then working tex code but you have mis-matched `\end` in the document, This looks weird to any human reading the source and will most lilley confuse editors and syntax checkers and probably latex-to-anything convertors. There is no need to do this at all as you can use the fancyvrb definition forms to define a custom _environment_ that includes your common options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is intended to explain the coming-into-being of the error-message.

It is not intended to provide a fix/workaround obeying good-practice-methods.

Resolving the issue according to good-practice-methods via `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment` is shown in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619382/118714).

Reasons for obeying good-practice-methods are given in [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619367/creating-a-macro-fancyverb-error#comment1546564_619367).*

---

TeX's eyes do pre-process .tex-input line by line:

- All characters of the line are converted to TeX's internal character-representation scheme which either is ASCII or is Unicode.
- **All space-characters at the right end of the line are removed.**
- **A character is appended at the end of the line whose code-point-number in TeX's internal character-representation scheme equals the value of the integer-parameter `\endlinechar`.**
- Then characters of the line get tokenized "on demand", i.e., whenever TeX's gullet needs tokens some of the characters get tokenized.

With the definition

```latex
\newcommand*{\VerbatimCustom}{  %<- spurious space token
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]   %<- spurious space token
}
```

spurious space-tokens come into being due to the `\endlinechar`-mechanism and `\endlinechar` at the time of tokeizing the definition having the value 13, denoting the carriage-return-character, and the carriage-return-character having catcode 5(return) which in turn implies the coming into being of

- no token at all if TeX's reading apparatus is in state "skipping blanks",
- an explicit space-token if TeX's reading apparatus is in state "middle of line",
- the control-word-token `\par` if TeX ´'s reading apparatus is in state "new line".

Afaik fancyvrb for its environments changes the catcode of `\endlinechar` from 5(return) to 12(other) so that in any case at the end of lines carriage-return-character-tokens of catcode 12(other) come into being.

Thus if you would do `\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]` directly, right behind the last token of the last argument of the environment there would not be a space-token but there would be a carriage-return-character-token of catcode 12(other) denoting the end of the line.

But due to the sequence coming from a macro-definition which includes a space-token, there is a space-token between the last token of the last argument of the environment and the carriage-return-character-token of catcode 12(other) denoting the end of the line.

The `Verbatim`-environment is implemented to raise an error-message if something is found between the last token of the last argument of the environment and the carriage-return-character-token of catcode 12(other) denoting the end of the line holding that last token.

Preventing the coming-into-being of these space-tokens by adding comment-chars at line-endings yields:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand*{\VerbatimCustom}{%%%%%%
 \begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm]%%%%%%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\VerbatimCustom
module GRAMMAR[] begin
  phylum Grammar;

  phylum Item;
  phylum Items := SEQUENCE[Item];

  phylum Production;
  phylum Productions := SEQUENCE[Production];

  constructor terminal(s: Symbol) : Item;
  constructor nonterminal(s: Symbol) : Item;
  constructor prod(nt: Symbol; children: Items) : Production;
  constructor grammar(prods: Productions) : Grammar;

  pragma root_phylum(type Grammar);
end;    
\end{Verbatim}
    \caption{Structure of a context-free grammar in APS}
    \label{fig:cfg-structure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When compiling the example, I don't get any error-messages.

---

*This answer is intended to explain the coming-into-being of the error-message.

It is not intended to provide a fix/workaround obeying good-practice-methods.

Resolving the issue according to good-practice-methods via `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment` is shown in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619382/118714).

Reasons for obeying good-practice-methods are given in [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619367/creating-a-macro-fancyverb-error#comment1546564_619367).*

Answer (score 2):

If you want that all `Verbatim` environments follow the specification

```
numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm
```

then the best way is to issue

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm}
```

Full example. Look inside it for more comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,xleftmargin=5mm}

\begin{document}

Some text before the verbatim environment.
Some text before the verbatim environment.
Some text before the verbatim environment.
Some text before the verbatim environment.

\begin{Verbatim}
This is {verbatim}
\another\line
\end{Verbatim}

You can also locally override a verbatim environment

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
This is almost verbatim in \LaTeX
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]